# How to fix accidentally changed password for phpmyadmin database user

Tags: phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin creates some database tables and the `phpmyadmin` user to access them. I let it generate a random password during the setup process. Unfortunately later I accidentally changed that password on the database, and now PhpMyAdmin has stored somewhere in configuration the value that is not matching the one on the database. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The connection data are stored in:

`/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf`

One can change the password on the database and then the value of `dbc_dbpass` in the file above.